# How to code a nested optimization problem in R

Tags: r, optimization

I have the following optimization problem out of a paper that I need to recreate in R [Optimization Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrnmX.png). It is one of the steps of a larger Algorithm. The setting is the following:

```
y_i is a 2-Dim vector. It can be interpreted as the i-th row of a matrix Y with dimension nx2 - this is known
psi^*_i is the i-th entry of a vector of length n - this is known
x is a 2-Dim vector - this is known
epsilon is a constant - this is known
y the two dimensional vector I am looking for.
```

I have trouble coding this problem. Something about the dimensions is confusing me. I imagined I could use optim() for the overall minimisation and approximate the maximum function on the inside somehow. I also thought that I could find the inner maximum using optim(), but I don't know how to work the maximisation over all n. I'm not that well versed in optimisation in R so I have sadly managed nothing. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you post the code here?  You seem to have pasted information, formatted as code, instead of the code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
n = 10
ymat = matrix(runif(n*2, -1000, 1000), ncol=2)
x = runif(2, -1000, 1000)
epsilon = runif(1, -1000, 1000)
psi = runif(n, -1000, 1000)

optim(
    par = c(1,1),
    fn = function(y) {
        max(sapply(1:n, function(i) {(ymat %*% y)[i,1] - psi[i]})) + 1/(2*epsilon) * sum((y - x)^2)
    }
)
```

You don't need to optimize the inner max, there's only a finite number of possibilities once you provide a specific value of `y`. Just a note, the result produces a value called `par`, this is the value R found to be optimal. Changing the value of `par` supplied to `optim` may give you better results. The key part is to work out how one would write the inner function if you were given a value for y:

```
max(sapply(1:n, function(i) {(ymat %*% y)[i,1] - psi[i]})) + 1/(2*epsilon) * sum((y - x)^2)
```

Note that the norm squared is just the sum of squares of the vector components. I'm assuming you know what [`sapply`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) and [`%*%`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/matmult.html) are. Once you know the inner function, you can create an outer function with an argument for `y` and pass that to optim (optim minimizes by default).

Comment: Thanks A LOT! That really helps and I understand it a lot better. I was really overthinking it :)

Comment: One follow-up question (purely hypothetical): if I were to change the setting slightly and have x not just be one 2-Dim vector but a matrix like ymat (basically n 2-Dim vectors), how would the code change?

Comment: Would you be maximizing ```sum((y-x)^2)```? Also, no problem! If you like the answer, it would be good to mark it as accepted!

Comment: Thanks for telling me about accepting the answer, just did it! Yes, for argument's sake let's say that would have to be maximised

Comment: There are couple ways of doing it. I generally prefer matrix arithmetic over ```sapply``` since it's usually faster in R (although not really necessary here). In this case, that would be ```max((t(y-t(x))^2 %*% c(1,1)))```. A more pleasant looking example would be ```max(sapply(1:n, function(i) {sum((y - x[i,])^2)}))```.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks, that's all really helpful and I understand it a lot better. Also, sorry for the late reply!